# TouchableHighlight to component?

Tags: react-native

Trying to figure out how to accomplish this. I have a component which has a function which I would like to trigger by using a outside TouchableHighlight. I know that must sound like an odd question...

Here is kinda what I mean:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.function.bind(this)}>
  <Component onPress={ somehow inherit on press} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

The reason I want to do it like this is there are other elements I want in the touchable highlight.. so I can't just add to the componet. I can add props to the component, so I was trying to figure out how to add funcs to it and trigger it that way

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Do you want the whole thing to be clickable and each child to have a different onpress function? or do you just want a container with components that are clickable?

Comment: The only thing I am going to have is pictures and images in that component.. so I want the whole thing to have a clickable effect, with just the component inheriting the onpress effect.. if that makes sense

Comment: ohh ok I think I get what you mean, basically when you click on the whole thing you want the onPress to call the function you have inside Component?

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways you can do this, but I think the easiest way is to use `refs`.

```
someFunction = () => {
  this.comp.watever() //whatever function you have inside Component that you want to invoke
}

<TouchableHighlight onPress={this.someFunction.bind(this)}>
  <Component ref={(comp) => this.comp = comp} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Was going to post the same suggestion, though I thought the OP meant it the other way around. So to add to this, if you want to access the TouchableHighlight's onPress, that can be done by having a `ref` on the `TouchableHighlight` and then having the child Component access it via `this.touchableRef.props.onPress`. For an example implementation, see [this sketch](https://snack.expo.io/rk0XqoiTe).